# useEffect hook is running an infinite loop even when a second argument is provided

Tags: reactjs

I can find similar questions asked dozens of times yet the provided solutions aren't working for me.  I have a `useEffect` hook which runs a function to return some data from my db.

```
const VenueDetails = ({ venue_details, fetchVenueDetails, id }) => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchVenueDetails(id);
  }, [venue_details]);

return (<div></div>)
}
```

`id` is a prop pulled from my url `<VenueDetails path="/venue-details/:id" />`

I have tried using an empty array as a second argument

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchVenueDetails(id);
  }, []);
```

but these solutions aren't working for me.  I'm sure I am missing something obvious but if someone could point it out for me that would be great.

I have also tried

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchVenueDetails(id);
  }, [id]);
```

and

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchVenueDetails(id);
  }, [venue_details, id]);
```

Edit: Adding more information.

Additionally my `fetchVenueDetails` function is in a `contextProvider`

```
  fetchVenueDetails = (venue_id) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(`/venues/details?venue_id=${venue_id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        const details = data;
        this.setState({
          venue_details: details,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error fetching venue details', error);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  };
```

Comment: Seems like `id` should be in the dependency array?

Comment: Agree with @Nick - the dependency array should only be those items that may change in the useEffect.  `id` is probably what you want.  venue_details is probably changing when you do a fetch, that's what's triggering the useEffect to run again.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for the same?

Comment: I am wondering if it is because my component is wrapped in a context provider

Comment: You are using `this.setState()` inside of an arrow function. Using `this.setState()` is only for class components. Why aren't you using `[loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)`?

Comment: @Samathingamajig. When I built the dataProvider I wasn't familiar with how to set it up using hooks.  Eventually I will update this.  The issue does seem to be with my loading state but not sure why.

Comment: @tdammon It's because you can't use `this.setState()` inside of an arrow function. I don't see you even rendering anything or using any data that is retrieved from `fetchVenueDetails()`

Comment: @Samathingamajig I omitted the render method since I don't think that is part of the problem.  Are you saying that you can never setState inside of an arrow function or just not inside of useEffect.  I haven't had any issues setting state inside context before.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious `fetchVenueDetails` and `id` as dependencies, literally the only things referenced in the effect callback? To me it appears that `fetchVenueDetails` likely updates `venue_details`, so you probably don't want to trigger the effect callback by what the callback updates.

Comment: @DrewReese, I just tried that and it didn't work for me.  I wasn't aware that you could have a function as a dependency.

Comment: Sure, any JS identifier that holds a value that isn't guaranteed to be a stable reference can be used as a react hook dependency. I just realized you mentioned that even with an empty dependency array that the infinite looping was still occurring... sounds like the component is being remounted versus simply rerendering. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of how the `VenueDetails` component is being rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

infinity loops happens because you `setState` in you contextProvider component.

as you `setState` it re-renders your contextProvider and the api call happens over and over again.

**The Solution**
instead directly updating your `state`, you have to `dispatch` an action and set your `loading` true or false.
and adding this dependency in `useEffect` would help it to re-render only if `loading` is change by your `reducer` action.

Untill and unless your `loading` state change by `reducer` action, your `useEffect` dependency not change and hence your components not render infinitely.

and you should not use `state` and `setState` in your functional component.

**try this :**

*Context Provider component*

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import { venueReducer } from '../reducers/venueReducer';

export const venueContext = createContext();

const venueContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [venueDetails, venueDispatch] = useReducer(venueReducer, {
    venue_details: null,
    loading: true
  });

  fetchVenueDetails = (venue_id) => {
    venueDispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_LOADING'}):

    fetch(`/venues/details?venue_id=${venue_id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        venueDispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_LOADING'}):
        const details = data;
        venueDispatch({type: 'FETCH_DETAILS', payload: details});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error fetching venue details', error);
        venueDispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_LOADING'}):
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchVenueDetails(id);
  }, [venueDetails.loading]);

  return (
    <venueContext.Provider value={{ venueDetails, venueDispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </venueContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default venueContextProvider;
```

*Reducer component*

```
export const venueReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_DETAILS':
      return {
        ...state,
        venue_details: action.payload
      }
    case 'TOGGLE_LOADING':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: !state.loading
      }
  }
}
```

adjust codes according to your application.
here context provider and reducer in their own directory so change reducer import to your reducer component.

i hope this works for you because it works for me.

**happy programing :)**

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same issue of rerendering the context provider when the `useReducer` state is updated? Dispatching actions to update the state *still updates the state*. Also, reducer functions should shallowly merge state updates, in your reducer the `TOGGLE_LOADING` action will wipe out the `venue_details` state.

Comment: no i have the same situation like 2 weeks ago and i tried this code and it worked for me. the infinte rendering issue solved. i have to add ...state in reducer which i forgot. thank :)

Comment: @DrewReese no it not rerender as loading state still be the same and chages if and only if reducer change it no matter how many time contextProvider renders. and the `useEffect` is only run if loading state change.

Comment: Oh, I see, so your suggestion is to also pass `loading` as a prop to `VenueDetails` and use as a dependency ***and*** a conditional guard to invoking `fetchVenueDetails`. Your solution/suggestion seemed to imply that using a `useReducer` hook alone would resolve the state update/render looping issue. You may want to make this part of your answer a bit more overt and clear.